# Why doesn't getMetadata show my callable methods as extrinsics in Substrate-node-template

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, extrinsic

When running `Substrate-node-template` - basically the Kitties - and with a callable eg `create_kitty()` as a `dispatchableResult` in the call pallet, what I assume to be an extrinsic in the metadata, this function is not returned by calling either `state_getMetadata` in javascript or the Polkadot js extrinsics. In fact, both show `causeError()` and `do-something()`. I have no idea where these methods come from and the actual callable method is not in the metadata at all. I really need clarification about this?

Comment: Hi @kim if you have the code committed to github or somewhere else it'll be easy to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

causeError() and do-something() are extrinsics from the substrate-node-template. You can check it here https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/src/lib.rs, or at the same location in your local copy of the node.

The kitties extrinsics are part of a different pallet, that should be located at the same pallets directory.

So if the kitties pallets is added to the node you are using it should be showed via the polkadot js under kitties pallet and not the template pallet.